# Função jquery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS:

```
.nav {
    width: 15%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #421;
    margin-top: 55px;
    float: left;
}
.nav-min {
    width: 5% !important;
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').click(function() {
            $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-min');
        });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <button class="btn btn-menu" id="btn">Menu</button>     
</nav>
```

Aqui tem testes que fiz e funcionaram 
http://jsfiddle.net/ukpm1uey/3/

porém não rodou no localhost, alguém sabe o que pode ser?, já verifiquei se esta salvando, mas mesmo assim não funciona de maneira alguma

Comment: No jsFiddle ele está funcionando! Qual é o seu objetivo ou que está tentando fazer para dizer que ele não está a funcionar?

Comment: Matheus, ainda esta muito difícil de entender qual e o seu problema, você poderia editar a sua pergunta adicionando mais informações? Quando tiver um tempo da uma lida aqui -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Então, eu queria fazer um menu que diminui ao clicar no botão, mas no meu código não esta funcionando :/, eu que montei o código do jsFiddle porém ele não funciona no meu código sendo que ele está praticamente limpo

Comment: tem certeza que vc colocou um tag link com o css inicial lá ? no jsfiddle, é só por na janela, mas no localhost precisa de um tag incluindo o css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No localhost deve ter colocado na mesma ordem que fez a pergunta.
Isso quer dizer.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-min');
   });
</script>
```

Está primeiro do que.:

```
<nav class="nav">
   <button class="btn btn-menu" id="btn">Menu</button>     
</nav>
```

Por isso não está a funcionar.
2 maneiras de ultrapassar

1. Colocar o script no fim da pasta
2. Alterar para.:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function() {
           $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-min');
        });
     });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram, deu certo :P